# C++ - Passing signals between threads of to functions of different classes?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Basic problem, but haven't been able to find solution. I need .notify_one() to be picked up by DERIVED_TWO, I've tested the code within the same class and it works fine?

```
#include <mutex>

class BASE
{
public:
    std::mutex(mu);
    std::condition_variable condition;
};

class DERIVED_ONE:public BASE
{
public:
   auto DoStuff()->void
   {
      std::unique_lock<mutex> lock(mu);
      //Do Stuff here...
      lock.unlock();
      condition.notify_one();
   }
};

class DERIVED_TWO:public BASE
{
public:
   auto DoMoreStuff()->void
   {
     std::unique_lock<mutex> lock(mu);
     condition.wait(lock);
     //Do even more stuff...
     lock.unlock();
   }
};
```

**SIDE NOTE:**
I could use a polymorphic object to pass messages between classes, although this seems a messy solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different instances of your classes will not share the same condition variable object unless you declare it static. And I also doubt that you would want them to.
I would implement a separate message queue class that could be instantiated as communication channels as needed and passed to the instances of your other classes at creation time.

Comment: can you explain further on how you would implement a message queue class?

Comment: There may be some new standard library features for this that I am not up to date on. Otherwise I would use a std::queue for holding message objects and protect pushing and popping of messages with a mutex. The message queue class can use an internal condition variable to implement a blocking pop() function.
However, I wouldn't be surprised if there is a library implementation of this already.